# Delete a document via Mongoose and Express by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to delete a connected account via Express and mongoose. When the user clicks on the button (confirmation on his willing to delete his account), I want his account remove from my user's collection.

My HTML:

```
<div class="button__remove">
     <button class="modal__submit modal__remove--ann" id="btn-remove">Annuler</button>
     <button class="modal__submit modal__remove--conf" onclick="location.href='/fr/supprimercompte'">Supprimer</button>
</div>
```

My Express code:

```
router.get('/supprimercompte', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    User.findOneAndDelete({user: req.user, id: req._id}, (err, tasks) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
            res.redirect('/fr/compte')
        } else {
            const response = {
            message: "Todo successfully deleted",
            user: req.user
            };
            res.status(200).send(response);
        }
   });
})
```

EDIT: Now my `res.send` is exactly what I want (the complete user object) but it doesn't delete from my mongoDB database ! What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you should path the id to the route like with `/:id` and send the `id` from the client side to the route

```
router.get('/supprimercompte/:id', (req, res) => {
        User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err) => {
          if(err){
              res.redirect("/fr/compte");
          } else {
              res.redirect("/fr");
          }
       });
    })
```

for client side

```
`/fr/supprimercompte/${id}`
```

Comment: The redirection works but it doesn't remove the object with this id.

Comment: when you console.log(req.params.id) is not undefind?

Comment: It is indeed. Is the problem relative to the fact that I don't have a DELETE request on my frontend ?